# Django Rest Framework AttributeError 'function' object has no attribute 'model' in router.register

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I try my first Django API using Django Rest Framework. Everything was fine, but I change something and stuck in this AttributeError and don't understand what to do. my code looks like in tutorial and it is half past 4 am, I really need help.
so,
this is the callback

```
    python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/api_demo/api_demo/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    router.register(r'developers', views.DevViewSet)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 72, in register
    base_name = self.get_default_base_name(viewset)
  File "/home/dev/test/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 152, in get_default_base_name
    return queryset.model._meta.object_name.lower()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'model'
```

this is url.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from developers import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'developers', views.DevViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api_demo', include(router.urls)),
]
```

this is views.py

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from developers.models import Developers
from .serializers import DevSerializer


class DevViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Developers.objects.all
    serializer_class = DevSerializer
```

and serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Developers

class DevSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Developers
        fields = ('name', 'surname', 'skills', 'education', 'employment_history')
```

and models

```
from django.db import models


class Education(models.Model):
    university =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year_of_graduation = models.DateField()


class Empl_history(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fr = models.DateField(verbose_name='from')
    to = models.DateField()


class Developers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    skills = models.ForeignKey('Skills', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    education = models.ManyToManyField(Education)
    employment_history = models.ManyToManyField(Empl_history)


class Skills(models.Model):
    SKILLS_CHOICES = (
    ('p', 'Python'),
    ('d',  'Django'),
    ('drf', 'Django Rest Framework'),
    )
    skills_choices = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SKILLS_CHOICES,)
```

and in settings I added this 'rest_framework' and 'developers' to INSTALLED_APPS, also I add this code in the end

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

Will be very thankfull for any advice and critic

Answer (score 5):

For the `queryset` declaration you need to call the function and return the `QuerySet` rather then pass the reference to the function e.g. change `queryset = Developers.objects.all` to `queryset = Developers.objects.all()`

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from developers.models import Developers
from .serializers import DevSerializer


class DevViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Developers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DevSerializer
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from developers import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'developers', views.DevViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```